# Topology int/cl question

Tags: general-topology

a) If $G=int(A)$, where $A$ is closed, then $G=int(cl(G))$? Does it also mean that $cl(G)=A$?

b) If $F=cl(B)$, where $B$ is open, then $F=cl(int(F))$? Does it also mean that $B=int(F)$?

|

I do not know if I had to do something else. I wrote directly:

a) $G=int(A)$, where $A$ is closed $\Rightarrow$ $G$ is open $\Rightarrow G=int(G)\Rightarrow G=int(cl(G))$.

$G=int(A) \Rightarrow cl(G)=cl(int(A))$, $A$ is closed $\Rightarrow A=cl(int(A)) \Rightarrow cl(G)=A$

a) $F=cl(B)$, where $B$ is open, $\Rightarrow F$ is close $\Rightarrow F=cl(F)\Rightarrow F=cl(int(F))$.

$F=cl(B)\Rightarrow int(F)=int(cl(B))$, $B$ is open $\Rightarrow int(cl(B)) = B \Rightarrow int(F)=B$

Comment: look for regular open and regular closed sets on the site.

Comment: a) $G=int(A)$, where $A$ is closed $\Rightarrow$ $G$ is open $\Rightarrow G=int(G)$ $\Rightarrow G\subseteq int(cl(G))$.

And I gave this example:

For $G=(0,1)$U$(1,2)$, $cl(G)=[0,2]$ and $int(cl(G))=(0,2)$.

 So $G ≠ int(cl(G))$.

Comment: Not an example as your $G= (0,1) \cup (1,2)$ is not of the form $\text{int}(A)$ with $A$ closed.

Comment: In your 4th line it does not immediately follow from $G=int(G)$ that $G=int(cl(G)).$ You must use the assumption that $G$ is not just any open set, but is the interior of a closed set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/24.pdf) I show (among other things) that for all subsets $A$ of a space $X$ we have

$$\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A)))) = \operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A))$$ and also

$$\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(A)))) = \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(A))$$

With this in hand you can solve all the questions:

your first set $G=\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A))$ as $A$ is closed etc.

Comment: To the proposer:  Suppose $\forall a[\, f(f(a))=f(a)\subset a\subset g(a)=g(g(a)) \,]$ and $\forall a,b\,[\,a\subset b\implies (f(a)\subset f(b)\land g(a)\subset g(b)\,].$ Let $I(a)=a.$ Then $fg(a)=ffg(a)=fIfg(a)\subset fgfg(a)\subset fgIg(a)=fgg(a)=fg(a).$ Therefore $fgfg(a)=fg(a).$ By a similar method, $gfgf(a)=gf(a).$ Here, $f(a)=int(a)$ and $g(a)=cl(a).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, we use little of interior and closure except such set properties to show the int/cl identities.

Comment: You can instead use the specific topological properties to show the int/cl identities by fighting through a lot of details.